# Check if value exists in another (joined) table and fill column in results accordingly

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=86f1d1e3608d64ee261260b23273d7fc)**

```
/* Table Sales */
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    campaign VARCHAR(255),
    quantity INT
);

INSERT INTO sales
(campaign, quantity)
VALUES 
("C001", "125"),
("C002", "300"),
("C003", "700"),
("C004", "900"),
("C005", "600");


/* Table Tranches */
CREATE TABLE tranches (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    campaign VARCHAR(255),
    tranches VARCHAR(255),
    quantity INT
);

INSERT INTO tranches
(campaign, tranches, quantity)
VALUES 
("C001", "t1", "125"),
("C001", "t2", "300"),
("C001", "t3", "700"),
("C003", "t1", "600"),
("C003", "t2", "465");
```

**Expected Result:**

```
   campaign     quantity   exists_in_tranches
    C001          125         yes
    C002          300         no
    C003          700         yes
    C004          900         no
    C005          600         no
```

---

In the abvoe example I have two tables called `sales` and `tranches`. 
As you can see some of the `campaigns` in table `sales` do have an entry in table `tranches`. Some others not.

In the column `exists_in_tranches` in the query result I want to check if a certain `campaign` from table `sales` exists in table `tranches` and if so it should be described as `yes` else it should be `no`.

---

Something like this:

```
SELECT
s.campaign,
s.quantity,
(CASE WHEN exists in table tranches THEN "yes" ELSE "no" END) AS exists_in_tranches
FROM sales s
LEFT JOIN tranches c ON c.campaign = s.campaign
GROUP BY 1;
```

---

How do I have to modify the `query` to achieve the expected result?

Comment: `CASE WHEN c.campaign IS NOT NULL THEN "yes" ELSE "no" END`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below - checking `is not null` and you don't need to add group by clause as you didn't use any aggregate function - **[DEMO Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=7cbdf65839ab22a4d85f97dbef2840e6)**

```
SELECT distinct
s.campaign,
s.quantity,
CASE WHEN c.campaign is not null THEN "yes" ELSE "no" END AS exists_in_tranches
FROM sales s
LEFT JOIN tranches c ON c.campaign = s.campaign
```

Answer (score 0):

E.g.:

```
SELECT s.*
     , MAX(CASE WHEN t.id IS NULL THEN 'no' ELSE 'yes' END) eit
  FROM sales s 
  LEFT 
  JOIN tranches t 
    ON t.campaign = s.campaign
 GROUP
    BY s.id
```